# wifi and the gwibber icons disappeared from the indicator applet

Tags: wireless, gnome-panel, gwibber, system-tray

They have disappeared from the indicator applet in the gnome-panel without asking me anything nor notifying. How can I bring them back in 11.04? I have rebooted and the situation persists.

The functionalities are still there but there is no icon. Only after connecting to a wifi the connection-icon (those lines that represent waves) appears, but there is never an icon showing that there is no wifi connection. Weird!

**EDIT.-** I Have found this logfile:

/home/user/.cache/indicator-applet-complete.log

Its modification date is recent and, after some tests, I think that it is generated every time I generate events on the applet.

```
Looking at Module: libapplication.so
Unable to load icon from file '<A0><97><8F>^A' because: Failed to open file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/statu
s/22/indicator-messages.svg': No such file or directory
Using user icon for 'Guest Session' from file: (null)
Connected to Application Indicator Service.
Request current apps
Building new application entry: :1.31  with icon: nm-no-connection at position 0
notify visible signal recieved
New calendar item
indicator-sound: new_volume_slider_widget
entry hint: Post message...
Get the username
Getting layout failed: Operation was cancelled
Restarting service 'com.canonical.indicator.messages' count 1
Updating username label
Unable to load icon from file '^X<D2><D2><FC><9E>^?' because: Failed to open file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
/status/22/indicator-messages.svg': No such file or directory
Unable to load icon from file '`<93><92>^A' because: Failed to open file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/2
2/indicator-messages.svg': No such file or directory
new_application_item ("Chat")
Unable to load icon from file '<A0><BB><94>^A' because: Failed to open file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/statu
s/22/nm-no-connection.svg': No such file or directory
new_application_item ("Ubuntu One")
Just caught a style change event
g_variant_get_string: assertion `value != NULL' failed
g_variant_get_string: assertion `value != NULL' failed
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Building new application entry: :1.32  with icon: gnome-power-manager at position 0
Unable to load icon from file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages.svg' because: Failed to open file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages.svg': No such file or directory
Signal: Entry Removed
Unable to load icon from file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages.svg' because: Failed to open file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages.svg': No such file or directory
Building new application entry: :1.32  with icon: gpm-battery-100 at position 0
Unable to load icon from file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages.svg' because: Failed to open file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages.svg': No such file or directory
Signal: Entry Removed
Unable to load icon from file '<B0>w^P<F0><9E>^?' because: Failed to open file '/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages.svg': No such file or directory
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
g_variant_get_string: assertion `value != NULL' failed
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
g_variant_get_string: assertion `value != NULL' failed
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
Changing calendar property: calendar-marks
```

but don't know how can I use it to fix the problem. It mentions missing icon files and broken links because in that directory there is only .svg files, links to .svg files, broken links to .svg files, and, it seems, there are missing .svg files too.

How to fix the problem and how can I know if there are more important problems in other places around?

Comment: Nobody answers. I would like to know whether this is a very difficult problem to solve or it is not very interesting. At least, I think, it is a very common problem since Ubuntu changed the way the gnome-panel is used.